# Three.js - Flash Light "Ring" Effect

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, flashlight, spotlight

I'm just wondering if anyone knows if it's possible to get a flash light effect with a THREE.SpotLight.

```
// Line 110
spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 0.5, 150);
spotLight.power = 6000;
spotLight.angle = 0.5;
spotLight.decay = 2;
spotLight.penumbra = 0.1;
spotLight.distance = 200;
```

I've set up a CodePen (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ALXNYQ - click render window to engage pointer lock) but I want the flash light to be more realistic. Here's an image with the desired effect:

[image: Flash Light "Ring" Effect]

I've tried looking around at documentation, thinking there would be a "map" of some kind that I could load - like, maybe it would have to be an alpha map or something. I'm still fairly new to the 3D gaming world, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding more spotlights with different angles and different parameter values to create that rings effect.

```
spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.5, 150);
spotLight.power = 4000;
spotLight.angle = 0.5;
.
.
.
spotLight2 = new THREE.SpotLight(0xCCCCCC, 0.5, 150);
spotLight2.power = 2000;
spotLight2.angle = 0.55;
.
.
.
flashLight.add(spotLight);
flashLight.add(spotLight.target);
flashLight.add(spotLight2);
flashLight.add(spotLight2.target);
```

You can see how it looks in [this](http://codepen.io/guardabrazo/pen/XjKGWk) codepen.
I think that you can achieve a similar effect to what you look for if you tweak the parameters.

Comment: Do you think there would be much impact on performance? Like, if I have a scene with 7 or 8 lights already, would it be wise to have 3 lights just for my flashlight? I guess that's up to me, ultimately. But thanks for the answer, nevertheless.

Comment: Definitely having many lights will impact on performance. You can try to disable the shadow casting of the extra spotlights. You can then monitor the performance using [Stats.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js/)